# Companion Won't Stay Equipped

Tags: fallout-4

These companions just want to make things difficult!

Every time I try to equip my companions with better weapons or armor from what their default is the companions switch back as soon as combat starts.

I understand that one has to force equip (Triangle for PS4), but why won't my companions stay equipped?

**UPDATE:** It seems that only Preston has the issue of keeping equipped armor on if you leave his armor in his inventory. All other companions appreciate their new getup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put some of this in an update to your question, but it should really be in an answer:

I've only had issues with Preston switching back to his original armor, which is a colonial duster. Everyone else sticks with what I tell them. This can be fixed by removing the armor from his inventory. If the armor is not visible when you attempt to trade with him, it should show up once you tell him to wear something else. After that, he *mostly* cooperates. I have occasionally had him magically generate a new duster and don it after a main Minutemen quest.

Any companion will switch back to their original weapon when they run out of ammo for all the weapons you've given them. Their original weapon uses magic companion ammunition and never runs out. You don't appear to be able to remove the default weapon from their inventory.

Comment: Removing Preston's minute man uniform does not change the fact that he doesn't keep other armor equipped. I believe he wears a duster that cannot be pick-pocketed off of him? I may be wrong.

Comment: @TylerWeaver The armor I refer to is the duster. Remove that when you trade with him. He should equip a Minuteman Outfit once you remove it. If you can't see his armor initially, tell him to equip some other armor and it should become visible.

Answer (score 3):

Supply ammunition for the weapons. If so remove the lesser weapons from their inventory.

Comment: Do I need to supply just a single bullet or a proper amount? And what about armor? How do I get the companions to keep it on?

Comment: @TylerWeaver I'd imagine 1 bullet to be enough as they never really run out ever. The armor im not sure about. Could the players relationship with the companion be a factor?

Comment: Okay. I will try it and give an update. What happens is I try to equip modified armor on Preston and he just switches back to his outfit in battle.

Comment: I needed to remove their weapon first. And I did not find a way for them to keep the armor on.

Comment: @AlexPerez My testing so far indicates that companions consume their ammo. They might not with their original weapon, haven't figured that out yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that companions consume ammo for the weapons you give them, and apparently (at least for me) I can't remove their original weapon. As for armor, I have practically given up on it. I don't know why they won't keep it equipped other than the fact that for whatever reason, what you are equipping them with is inferior to their base armor. I would really like to know the answer to this one myself.

Comment: You are correct in that they seem to require ammo for guns. I have given Preston power armor to use (companions don't drain fusion cores). After completing The Castle, Preston won't even talk to me. He stole the power armor as well and defaulted back to his original costume.